# Upgrade from Oracle 9.0 to Oracle 10.0 SunOS, fatal: libclntsh.so.9.0: open failed

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle10g, oracle9i, sunos

We upgraded our DB Server from Oracle 9.0 to Oracle 10.0 under SunOS, but there is something wrong with linkage, since a lot of application stop working with libclntsh.so.9.0 error.

```
ldd sqlplus
```

shows

```
libclntsh.so.9.0 =>       (file not found)
```

I tried to create a symbolic link but nothing seems to be working

```
ln -s $ORACLE_HOME/lib32/libclntsh.so.10.1 /usr/bin/libclntsh.so.9.0
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

### The solution is as follows:

a. Run the **changePerm.sh** script.

b. bounce LISTENER

c. bounce SID

Answer (score 0):

Is it complaining about a new and unresolved variable ? If not check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem exactly. And LD_LIBRARY_PATH is well defined too :(

Answer (score 0):

It was an architectural problem since I installed Oracle 10.0 64Bit and our applications compiled for 32Bit architecture, so I recompiled Oracle client.